# connect a line to the car in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rotation, matrix-multiplication

```js
var car;
var front;
var back;
var carpoint1;
var carpoint2;
var carpoint3;
var carpoint4;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transportation-2-4/60/transportation-2-flat-036-racing-car-top-512.png';


function startGame() {
    car = new move(12, 20, "red", 600, 300);
    pg.start();
}

var pg = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1200;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateframe, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            pg.keys = (pg.keys || []);
            pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },    
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function move(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = pg.context;
        ctx.save();

  getcarpoints(this.x, this.y, this.angle);
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.width / -2, this.height / -2,20,40); 

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(600, 800);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(carpoint1[0], carpoint1[1]);
  ctx.stroke();
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);

    }
}

function getcarpoints(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 carpoint1=[getrotatedx(prex,prey,rotation), getrotatedy(prex,prey,rotation)];
 carpoint2=[carpoint1[0], carpoint1[1]+40];
 carpoint3=[carpoint2[0]+20, carpoint2[1]+40];
 carpoint4=[carpoint3[0]+20, carpoint3[1]];
// console.log(carpoint1[0]);
}
function getrotatedx(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 piangle=Math.abs((rotation/ Math.PI * 180)%360);
 newx=Math.cos(piangle)*prex+(-(Math.sin(piangle)*prey));
 return newx;
}
function getrotatedy(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 piangle=Math.abs((rotation/ Math.PI * 180)%360);
 newy=Math.sin(piangle)*prex+(Math.cos(piangle)*prey);
 return newy;
}

function updateframe() {
    pg.clear();
    car.moveAngle = 0;
    car.speed = 0;
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[37]) { if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.moveAngle= 5; } if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]){car.moveAngle = -5; } }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[39]) { if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.moveAngle= -5; } if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]){car.moveAngle = 5; } }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]) {car.speed= 5; }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.speed= -5; }
    car.newPos();
    car.update();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script src="control.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my full code in snippet. I am trying to make a line from one fix point to the car... and this is the problem.

Now when is horizontal at any x point it works perfectly but the moment car turn the angle changes and it all messes up! you can see that when you turn the car (use arrow and left or right arrow at the same time) the line jumps.

Note: it is my project requirement to do it with 2d rotation matrix which means I can't make the line before i restore the canvas.

carpoint1,2,3,4 are the corners of car but right now I am just working with the carpoint1.

Do something so getrotatedx and getrotatedy always gives correct value that are car coordinates after matrix rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);` instead of `ctx.lineTo(carpoint1[0], carpoint1[1]);`

```js
var car;
var front;
var back;
var carpoint1;
var carpoint2;
var carpoint3;
var carpoint4;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/transportation-2-4/60/transportation-2-flat-036-racing-car-top-512.png';


function startGame() {
    car = new move(12, 20, "red", 600, 300);
    pg.start();
}

var pg = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1200;
        this.canvas.height = 600;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateframe, 20);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            pg.keys = (pg.keys || []);
            pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            pg.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
        })
    },
    stop : function() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    },    
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function move(width, height, color, x, y, type) {

    this.type = type;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speed = 0;
    this.angle = 0;
    this.moveAngle = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = pg.context;
        ctx.save();

  getcarpoints(this.x, this.y, this.angle);
        ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
        ctx.rotate(this.angle);
  ctx.drawImage(img, this.width / -2, this.height / -2,20,40); 

  ctx.restore();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 150);//fixed point
  ctx.lineTo(600, 800);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(300, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y);
  ctx.stroke();
    
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.angle += this.moveAngle * Math.PI / 180;
        this.x += this.speed * Math.sin(this.angle);
        this.y -= this.speed * Math.cos(this.angle);

    }
}

function getcarpoints(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 carpoint1=[getrotatedx(prex,prey,rotation), getrotatedy(prex,prey,rotation)];
 carpoint2=[carpoint1[0], carpoint1[1]+40];
 carpoint3=[carpoint2[0]+20, carpoint2[1]+40];
 carpoint4=[carpoint3[0]+20, carpoint3[1]];
// console.log(carpoint1[0]);
}
function getrotatedx(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 piangle=Math.abs((rotation/ Math.PI * 180)%360);
 newx=Math.cos(piangle)*prex+(-(Math.sin(piangle)*prey));
 return newx;
}
function getrotatedy(prex,prey,rotation)
{
 piangle=Math.abs((rotation/ Math.PI * 180)%360);
 newy=Math.sin(piangle)*prex+(Math.cos(piangle)*prey);
 return newy;
}

function updateframe() {
    pg.clear();
    car.moveAngle = 0;
    car.speed = 0;
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[37]) { if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.moveAngle= 5; } if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]){car.moveAngle = -5; } }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[39]) { if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.moveAngle= -5; } if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]){car.moveAngle = 5; } }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[38]) {car.speed= 5; }
    if (pg.keys && pg.keys[40]) {car.speed= -5; }
    car.newPos();
    car.update();
}


startGame()
```

```css
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```